# Does Jupyter Notebook have a file rename hook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've written a custom pre_save_hook that's similar to [the one that the Jupyter Notebook docs provide](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/savehooks.html). The one I've written adds metadata to a notebook when the notebook is saved. However, the pre_save_hook doesn't seem to get called when a notebook is renamed. Is there something similar to the pre_save_hook for renaming a notebook?